# How do I delete material in 'Video' in the imovie app

Tags: iphone, video, imovie

When I open imovie there are three choices Video Projects of Theater.  I want to delete what is in the video file but can't work out how to do this as when I enter this there are all the video clips but no menu to do anything but view them.  Can anybody help please.

Answer (score 1):

The videos in the "Video" section can be deleted from the "Photos" application.  iMovie can include those videos when making a project, but, it cannot delete them directly.